# joining two tables and produce the table with same value in two different rows

Tags: sql, sas

I have two tables.

table 1

```
CRS Name            Total_Exposure_Amount

Ackerman & Co LLC    152,823.00
Arbeit investments   489,756,203.00
Ashton woods         4,785,683.25
Alience Residential  235,694.58
```

Table 2

```
CRS_Name             Outstanding_balance
Ackerman & Co LLC     123,566.23
Ackerman & Co LLC     0.21
Arbeit investments    2,331.26
Arbeit investments    32,566.00
Ashton woods          123,462
Ashton Woods          36,245.24
Alience Residential   32,134.26
```

The final table I need is like this

Final Table

```
CRS_Name             Outstanding_Balance         Relations_TBE
Ackerman & Co LLC    123,566.23                   152,823.00
Ackerman & Co LLC    0.21                         152,823.00
Arbeit Investments   2,331.26                     489,756,203.00
Arbeit Investments   32,566.00                    489,756,203.00
Ashton woods         123,462                      4,785,683.25
Ashton Woods         36,245.24                    4,785,683.25
Alience Residential  32,134.26                    235,694.58
```

Is there anyway we can do it using Proc sql? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple join between the two table based on the common key between the two table which CRS_Name in this case.

```
 proc sql;
        create table final_table as
        select a.CRS_NAme,b.Outstanding_Balance, a.Outstanding_balance
        from table_1 a, table_2 b
        where a.CRS_Name= b.CRS_Name;
    quit;
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.